# Mounting a Luks partition

Tags: backup, ssd, lvm, luks, cryptsetup

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I have backed up a drive with all its partitions using the command

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/ubuntu.img
```

`/dev/sda` is an ssd which has Ubuntu 18.04 installed with full encryption.

Before I wipe this drive and re-purpose it, I want to make sure the backup has worked.

I have tried the following by searching askubuntu and other stackexchange sites:

```
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 /media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/ubuntu.img 
[sudo] password for oshirowanen: [password goes here]
losetup: /media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/ubuntu.img: failed to set up loop device: Device or resource busy

sudo losetup -P /dev/loop100 /media/oshirowanen/external-drive/backups-2019/ubuntu.img 
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop100p5 img5
Enter passphrase for /dev/loop100p5: [password goes here]

cd /mnt
mkdir img5
sudo mount /dev/mapper/img5 img5
mount: /mnt/img5: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Both `cryptsetup` and `lvm2` are already installed.

If this is not the best way to backup the drive, please suggest something else which is better.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

```
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ sudo pvscan
[sudo] password for oshirowanen: 
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 on /dev/mapper/img5 was already found on /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt.
  WARNING: Disabling lvmetad cache which does not support duplicate PVs.
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 on /dev/mapper/img5 was already found on /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 prefers device /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt because device is used by LV.
  PV /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [232.16 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [232.16 GiB] / in use: 1 [232.16 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ sudo vgscan
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 on /dev/mapper/img5 was already found on /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt.
  WARNING: Disabling lvmetad cache which does not support duplicate PVs.
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 on /dev/mapper/img5 was already found on /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 prefers device /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt because device is used by LV.
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ sudo vgs
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  WARNING: Use multipath or vgimportclone to resolve duplicate PVs?
  WARNING: After duplicates are resolved, run "pvscan --cache" to enable lvmetad.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 on /dev/mapper/img5 was already found on /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 prefers device /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt because device is used by LV.
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 232.16g    0 
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ sudo lvs
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.
  WARNING: Use multipath or vgimportclone to resolve duplicate PVs?
  WARNING: After duplicates are resolved, run "pvscan --cache" to enable lvmetad.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 on /dev/mapper/img5 was already found on /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt.
  WARNING: PV udJ9tW-vls3-YQOz-cLkW-lTsh-DMCF-zrfLD0 prefers device /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt because device is used by LV.
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- <231.21g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----  980.00m                                                    
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ ls /dev/mapper/
control  img5  sda5_crypt  ubuntu--vg-root  ubuntu--vg-swap_1
oshirowanen@desktop:~$
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo losetup -P /dev/loop100 /media/ubuntu/external-drive/backups-2019/ubuntu.img 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop100p5 img5
Enter passphrase for /dev/loop100p5: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo mkdir img5
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/img5 img5
mount: /mnt/img5: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo pvscan
  PV /dev/mapper/img5   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [232.16 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [232.16 GiB] / in use: 1 [232.16 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 232.16g    0 
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-a----- <231.21g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-a-----  980.00m                                                    
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ ls /dev/mapper/
control  img5  ubuntu--vg-root  ubuntu--vg-swap_1
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$
```

Comment: run `sudo pvscan` `sudo vgscan` `sudo lvscan` and then `sudo vgs` and `sudo lvs`, update your question with the last two commands output, `ls /dev/mapper/` might be helpful too.

Comment: @Ravexina, outputs added to OP as requested.

Comment: There are conflicts between main disk and your backup on `/dev/loopxxx`, Boot into a live Ubuntu system, then try to re-check your backup.

Comment: @Ravexina, please see update 2 from liveusb.  I get the same error message `unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.` but different values from the scans.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt` is what you should do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got here is LUKS + LVM, what you are doing is unlocking the LUKS encrypted partition and then trying to mount a LVM physical volume. that's wrong you should mount the logical volume on your volume group `ubuntu-vg`.

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt
```

Summery:

```
Backup file: /media/ubuntu/external-drive/backups-2019/ubuntu.img
Accessible as a loop device at: /dev/loop100
Unlocked on: /dev/mapper/img5
PV: /dev/mapper/img5
VG: ubuntu-vg
LV: ubuntu-vg/root
LV Location: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root
```